# Prevent main.dart on FCM onLaunch

Tags: android, firebase, flutter, dart, firebase-cloud-messaging

Is there a proper way/flutter-firebase guidelines to prevent a flutter app to re-start from main.dart when loading from `onLaunch()` of FCM firebase notification .

I can see ,`onLaunch` being triggered but soon main.dart overrides it .

```
_fcm.configure(
  // Called when the app is in the foreground and we receive a push notification
  onMessage: (Map<String, dynamic> message) async {
    print('onMessage: $message');
  },
  // Called when the app has been closed comlpetely and it's opened
  // from the push notification.
  onLaunch: (Map<String, dynamic> message) async {
    print('onLaunch: $message');
    _serialiseAndNavigate(message); //THIS WORKS , BUT SUDDENLY main.dart KICKS IN .
  },
  // Called when the app is in the background and it's opened
  // from the push notification.
  onResume: (Map<String, dynamic> message) async {
    print('onResume: $message');
    _serialiseAndNavigate(message);
  },
);
```

Comment: Not quite following. The `onLaunch` event is being raised because the app is starting due to the notification being clicked. What do you expect to happen?

Comment: @aqwert suppose main.dart has been instructed to go to page A , but onLaunch has been told to go to page B . Now on click of notification tell me which page will the user see ?

Comment: You do not navigate within the onLaunch handler. Set a variable like the data of the notification and then when the MaterialApp runs, check if that variable has been set then navigate to Page B

Answer (score 0):

When you click on the FCM notification, app is likely to be launch from `onLaunch` method and it does invoke the `main.dart`. I would suggest please try to inject `fcm.configure()` not in `main.dart`, instead you can inject in whatever stateful widget/screen you want to invoke the screen directly to launch when notification gets clicked (`onLaunch`).

ex:-> main.dart -> homescreen.dart -> somescreen -> forever flow

if you want to invoke `onLaunch` to open homescreen.dart, run the `fcm.configure()` to homescreen.dart -> `initState`

Remember it will also run main.dart at first as flutter starts the flow of the app from main.dart itself, you cannot change it I guess, but on notification tap it will not open main.dart, instead it will launch homescreen.dart.